# how to use slider and timer together in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, slider, flutter-slider, flutter-timer

I am very new for Flutter AND I need your small help.
I want to use images in slider which I already created no problem in that but I need one advice I want to slide that slider using timer.
How can i do that please help. I a, stuck on this problem from 2 weeks.

Thank you

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider 
this could be helpful, install the plugin and try

Answer (score 0):

```
CarouselSlider(
   items: items,
   options: CarouselOptions(
      height: 400,
      aspectRatio: 16/9,
      viewportFraction: 0.8,
      initialPage: 0,
      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
      reverse: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      onPageChanged: callbackFunction,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   )
 )
```

user carousel slider packages to slider with timer